# Combine multiple xml files based on criteria

Tags: xml, language-agnostic

I have an xml file that is received on a weekly basis.  The file contains approximately 40 "Activities" which my client has available.  Of the 40 I only need 8.  In order to reduce the time it takes to process the file, I need to select the 8 "Activities" and then combine them into a single xml file.  The single file will have the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
     <Activity> ... </Activity>
     <Activity> ... </Activity>
     <Activity> ... </Activity>
</Data>
```

The Activity tag will contain approximately 20 - 30K lines.  When I have the file fully expanded we have approximately 1.5MM lines.  This is why I am anxious to limit what I have to process.  One of my coworkers has written a java script to create a new xml file for each Activity in the tree.  For each of the files, he has named the file based on a tag .  The resulting file is looks like 123456.xml.

What I need to do from here is to select the 7-8 files that I need based on the file name, combine the files into a single xml, and then save the file as whatever.xml.  I will have a file that can contain the ActivityIDs that are necessary for each week's processing.

I am hoping to do this in a relatively quick fashion as I am currently searching for the Activity ID in the xml and then manually building the resulting file.

Also, the resulting file needs to be zipped, but this is a nice to have feature and can be done manually.

I am open to suggestions including language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use python and BeautifulSoup for this-- easy xml parsing, good libraries for zipping etc. And BeautifulSoup performs pretty well with big files, too.

Good luck!

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile